# Lifting homomorphism when module is direct summand of free module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence, projective-module

Let $N,M,M',N'$ be modules such that $F = N \oplus N'$ is a free module.

Let further $f: M \rightarrow M''$ be a surjective homomorphism.

I would like to show that for any homomorphism

$\phi: N \rightarrow M''$ there is a homomorphism $\psi: N \rightarrow M$

such that $f \circ \psi = \phi$, but cannot see any way to do this.

Comment: Hint : first extend $\phi$ to $F$, then use a basis of $F$.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with extending $\phi$ to $F$.

Comment: Well $N$ is a submodule of $F$, so extending $\phi: N\to M''$ to $F$ means finding a morphism $F\to M''$ such that the restriction to $N$ is the original $\phi$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints.** Let $p_N:F\to N$ be the projection on $N$. Use a basis of $F$ and find $g:F\to M$ such that $f\circ g=\phi\circ p_N$. Now set $\psi=g_{|N}$, the restriction of $g$ to $N$.